# An error occurred while getting provider information from the database

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

Getting the error:

> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string.
>   Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
>   ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

I get the same error when trying to do an `Add-Migration`

Here is my connection string, I need to access my local SQL server and NOT SQLEXPRESS.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ReaderInsightDbContext" 
         connectionString="data source=localhost\MSSQLSERVER;
                         initial catalog=ReaderInsight;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My DB is located:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

So my instance is MSSQLSERVER. Not sure what is going on. It first worked just fine, but after I changed my code to use the UOW pattern, this is happening. I also upgraded from EF 4.3 to EF5. Same issue.

I tried many variations of the data source in the connection string, none work, here are some examples:

- localhost\MSSQLSERVER
- .\MSSQLSERVER
- //localhost\MSSQLSERVER
- (local)\MSSQLSERVER
- 127.0.0.1\MSSQLSERVER

If I do .\SQLEXPRESS it works.

Comment: Tried it and it pointed to SQLEXPRESS and not sqlserver

Comment: Maybe something that may help to figure this out, I deleted all migration files generated by the Add-Migration since my DB only existed on my local machine and I was having some issue with foreign keys, so I decided to generate a clean migration for the now stable DB. Not sure why that would have an impact though.

Comment: See this 
[post.][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167363/mvc3-music-store-tutorial-connection-string-issue


Looks like you are missing the MARS setting.

Answer (score 8):

Managed to get it resolved.

Bottom line manually deleting the migration files causes issues.

Made sure my connection string looks like so:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ReaderInsightDbContext" 
     connectionString=
     "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ReaderInsight;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Performed an `Update-Database -TargetMigration:$InitialDatabase` which did not work as it said there is still pending changes.

So I performed

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(     
  new System.Data
            .Entity
            .DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ReaderInsightDbContext>());
```

in the global.asax file.

Commented it out, so it wont run again. I then did a Add-Migration Init and it recreated the script for the entire DB and when I ran Update-Database worked like a charm.

Comment: instead of Data Source=.; set Data Source=localhost; in your connectionstring

Answer (score 4):

I got it solved by setting the start up project in my solution to the entity dll project ( having app.config file ). I did set the "Default project" in Package Manager Console window to the correct entity dll project but that did't work. For details

[Entity Framework 6 with SQL Server 2012 gives System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583980/entity-framework-6-with-sql-server-2012-gives-)
system-data-entity-core-providerin

Comment: Yes!  I had the same problem.  I had changed my startup project to something else and migrations stopped working.  Thanks for your answer;  this was driving me nuts.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It worked.  Weird solution, but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

See this post:

[MVC3 Music Store Tutorial Connection String issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167363/mvc3-music-store-tutorial-connection-string-issue)

Looks like you are missing the MARS setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I changed my password that SQL Server won't start. Check that :)

Answer (score 0):

Check that, The SQL Server you are using in the connection string is started or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the other day. The reason was my MSSQL server version. 
I tried to use VS2010 and SQL SERVER 2008 and then it didn't work.
It worked fine with SQL Express which comes with VS2010 (and it wasn't started) but not with SQL SERVER.

Answer (score -3):

I used this with VS 2010 and it worked:

1. Added User Instance=true
2. Used the data source .\SQLEXPRESS