# Deployment to Azure from Jenkins not working because of "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred" (Error 26)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure, jenkins

A friend of mine setup a Jenkins build server with automatic deployment to Azure. The website used to work fine after deployment, but after we branched our solution and then merged it again (after changing from .aspx to razor) the website displays the following error (locally everything works fine):

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured 
to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - 
Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Unfortunately we (the two that are left behind) cannot ask our friend how to solve this since he is on a vacation.

After searching on the internet we think it has something to do with our connection string that might be changed. Locally we can connect to the remote Azure database via the "Connect to Database" option in the Visual Studio Server Explorer. When we right click this connection and copy the connection string into our web.config and/or publish profile we still get the same error message on the website.

Our connection string in the web.config looks like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data 
Source=*******.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=blablaAszH;Persist 
Security Info=True;User ID=testserver@blabla;Password=ourpassword" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I do not know what other relevant information I can post but if you ask for it I will place it here.

(The main goal is actually just to deploy the website. But we cannot do this via Visual Studio since only our friend knows the username and password and he's disconnected from the world. These are not the same as in the connection string since when we publish from Visual Studio it says the web deployment task failed because of a wrong username and password. So we need to publish via committing our project to SVN and Jenkins doing the deployment.)

Does anyone here know how to solve this issue or with what it might be related?